# Pushing new value to array wiping off old

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to push new value to an array and want to keep old one as well but old value is wiping off with below code.

```
let abText = (text) => {
  let query = [];
  let a = text.map(
    (script) => {
     let value = createFromMethod(script);
     query = {...query, value};
    }
  );
  console.log(query);
  return query;
};
```

`createFromMethod` will return an object each time of map
iteration and i need to return all these objects as array of object.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: you are initializing your array (let query = [];) inside method. It should be outside.

Comment: What is this line supposed to do `query = {...query, query};`? Also what is the use of `value` variable?

Comment: @HassanImam My bad, updated the line

Comment: (1) also, `query = {...query, query}` would make `query` an object, not an array, and (2) it's code smell to change external data inside `map()`

Comment: Also, you are initializing `query` as an array and then inside the `array#map` you convert it to an object. What does it suppose to be?

Comment: What's with `a`? Why do you create an array of `undefined`s that is never used after declaration?

Comment: I think you need something like this `let abText = text => text.map(script => createFromMethod(script))};`. But I am not sure.

Comment: @Andreas How to correct it? Can you please guide?

Comment: No, because I have absolutely no clue what this function is supposed to do :/

Comment: @Andreas I have updated the post with more details. Could you please help me now?

Comment: Hassan already gave you the solution. But please. Have a look at how `.map()` works and what it does. And have a look at arrays and how you modify them.

Answer (score 1):

```
const query = [];

let abText = (text) => {

    text.map(script => createFromMethod(script)).forEach(obj => query.push(obj));

    return query;

};
```

OR

```
const query = [];

let abText = (text) => {

    const newObjs = text.map(script => createFromMethod(script));

    query = [...query, ...newObjs];

    return query;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming I understand the question - which is not very likely, and that `createFromMethod` simply returns some object, you want to push each of these objects into an array which is returned in `abText`.

In this case, line 6 is muddled up.

Change line 6 from `query = {...query, value};` to `query = [...query, value];`

- This is because `query = {...[1,2,3], 5} => error missing ":" token`
- and `query = [...[1,2,3], 5] => result: [1,2,3,5]`

Comment: For tesing purposes, I declared `createFromMethod` as the following: `createFromMethod = txt => {return {test:txt}};`